# How to read environment variables in a Python-based ECS task

Tags: amazon-ecs

Maybe this is pretty silly, but if I create a ECS task definition (see for example Step 6 of https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/), how can I read the environment variables inside my Python script?

Is it as simple as os.environ["AWS_REGION"]? or should I need to use the boto3 route, eg, http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_task_definition?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide the *environment* portion of the ECS task definition JSON, those will be readable from the container, so you should be able to use those `os.environ['ENVVAR']` lines.

```
            'environment': [
                {
                  'foo': 'bar'
                }
            ]
```

would be accessible via bash as `$foo` so there's no reason your code can't access it.